# Uncaught ReferenceError: "method" is not defined

Tags: javascript, object, methods, referenceerror

I've created a javascript object

```
var Article = function(data) {
    this.foo = data,
    this.get_more_data = function() {
        // do something, get a response
        show_data(response);
    },
    this.show_data = function(bar) {
        //do something with bar;
    }
};
```

which works fine when the method show_data is written without this. but then it isn't accessible outside of the object.  With this. I get a "Uncaught ReferenceError" from the Chrome console.

Why is this?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you calling the method?

Comment: The error occurs on just the code above, without even calling show_data from outside the object. I call article.get_more_data from my code after var article = new Article(value);

Comment: Perhaps you should use semicolons instead of colons? this.foo = data; and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be calling `show_data` as a method of `this`, not as a function scoped to the current context:

```
var Article = function(data) {
    this.foo = data,
    this.get_more_data = function() {
        // do something, get a response
        this.show_data(this.foo);
    },
    this.show_data = function(bar) {
        console.log(bar);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't actually use echo on my code, just a typo in my question example code. Oops.